# Autolayout: Able to shrink to 2 lines when to short

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, multiline, truncate

So, I have 2 labels, name them A (on the left) and B (on the right). A has `numberOfLines = 2`.

They have horizontal spacing restrict (≥ 10)

If B is too long, A should truncate to 2 lines, but if A should truncate (A...), then truncate B instead.

Please guide me how to setup layout + constraint with this. This probably havs something with hugging & resistance priority, but I'm not sure which values should I put to achieve my goal.

[image: sample]

**EDIT**

So, due to the confusion, I'll update what should be:

```
Case 1: 
This is a long long  ---  this label is long enough
text

Case 2:
This is a long --- this label is too long it has to be trunca...
long text

Case 3:
This is short --- this is short too.

Case 4 (shouldn't be like this)
This is a  --- this label is too long but it doesn't truncate.
long...
```

Comment: Please **If B is too long, A should truncate to 2 lines, but if A should truncate (A...), then truncate B instead.** This line. Didn't get this.

Comment: " but if A should truncate (A...), then truncate B instead." - Pardon??

Comment: maybe what he meant is if B is longer than 2 lines, then truncate A instead to show full B, that probably need to constraint A width with greater than or equal

Comment: You will need to use code. There is no way for Autolayout by itself to determine "if text wraps to only two lines (if it doesn't truncate), do this, if it truncates, do that."